# acessibility mode changing

Tags: c#, winforms

I had two forms form1 and form2 .I need to acess the datas of toolbar components of form 2 from form1
it may be like 
 string s= form1.lblstatus.text ;
and when I searched  it says the control in form 2 must be declared private to acess like this but how can we set the acessibility mode for labels and other controls in vs2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it `public`, not `private`.
You can do this in Designer mode (what it seems you're using) of VS2010 as follows:

Click on the Control you need to access.

On the bottom-right of the screen, in the "Properties" window, scroll down to "Modifiers" and click on it.

Click on the arrow that appears to the right of "Private".

Click on "Public".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only reading the data, you could create a public, read-only property on Form2.

```
public string Status
{
    get
    {
        return lblStatus.Text;
    }
}
```